# Regex: to match certain chars but no space allowed

Tags: php, regex, whitespace

I have this regex:

```
(.*^(?=.{16,25}$)(?=.*[a-z]{1,})(?=.*[A-Z]{1,})(?=.*[0-9]{1,})(?=.*\W{1,8}).*$)
```

To match a password(string) on:

- 16-25 length
- 1 to many a-z
- 1 to many A-Z
- 1 to many 0-9
- 1 to many symbols

But I don't want `\s` and I don't know how to put it in the regex.

Any suggestions?

> I edit the original limit chars{1,8} to {1,}

Comment: Are you sure the pattern works at all? Do you mean to require 1 to 8 *consecutive* lower, uppercase letters, digits and symbols? The `.*` at the start invalidates the length check lookahead. Try [`^(?=\S{16,25}$)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){1,8})(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){1,8})(?=(?:\D*\d){1,8})(?=(?:\w*\W){1,8})\S*$`](https://regex101.com/r/fH8mF7/1) that allows 1 to 8 chars you require anywhere in the string. `\S` should be used to disallow whitespaces.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler and (potentially) more secure to just say 16-25 non-whitespace characters rather than arbitrarily declaring that the first 1-8 must be lower-case, the next upper case, then numbers then symbols? Then you'd just need `/^[^\s]{16,25}$/` : https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: `/^[^\s]{16,25}$/` would allow a password full of `a`'s

Comment: @ThomasAyoub ... and?

Comment: @CD001 and that's not what OP's asking :)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub heheh - fair point, but I was trying to ascertain the purpose of that arbitrary (and weird) format for the passwords.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your pattern doesn't fail, if there are more than 8 of e.g. lowercase letters (though i doubt that that is a useful restriction)

Comment: @SebastianProske: I do not know what OP needs anyway, I just showed a way to require something. Most probably those lookaheads must be negative, like `(?!(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){9})`, etc.

Comment: I suspect actually - I've slightly got the wrong end of the stick from reading the RegExp ... I think what's actually required is much simpler; a string 16-25 characters in length that must contain 1-8 of lower-case, upper-case numbers and symbols each, anywhere. Which makes a bit more sense.

Comment: But why would one ever restrict it to 8 lowercase only? I hope I never have to find a password fitting that pattern when I try to register somewhere.

Comment: @SebastianProske - 8 lower-case wouldn't work, it would still need at least one upper-case, 1 number, 1 symbol and the full string must be at least 16 characters long. It's still a bit arbitrary but not as mad as I first assumed.

Comment: @CD001 I think you got me wrong. 1 to 8 in my eyes means it has to fail if there are 9 lowercase (and all other conditions fulfilled)

Comment: @SebastianProske ... oh yeah, good point :)

Comment: @CD
Well It is like this " I think what's actually required is much simpler; a string 16-25 characters in length that must contain 1-8 of lower-case, upper-case numbers and symbols each, anywhere" examp: aWoeed1#fde39393aii
is valid...

The 1, 8 is actually not working so it works like {1,}

But I need without \s...

Comment: Your example string `aWoeed1#fde39393aii` is not valid because it contains more than 8 `a-z` characters.

Comment: @RoYoMi true that's why I changed the {1,8} to {1,}

Comment: If only one is required, then you don't need a quantifier: `(?=.*[a-z])`.

Answer (score 2):

## Description

```regex
^(?=(?:[^a-z]*?[a-z]){1,8}(?!.*?[a-z]))(?=(?:[^0-9]*?[0-9]){1,8}(?!.*?[0-9]))(?=(?:[^A-Z]*?[A-Z]){1,8}(?!.*?[A-Z]))(?=(?:[^!-\/:-@[-`{-~]*?[!-\/:-@[-`{-~]){1,8}(?!.*?[!-\/:-@[-`{-~]))[a-zA-Z0-9!-\/:-@[-`{-~]{16,25}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- require the string to be 16-25 length
- require 1 to 8 a-z characters anywhere in the string and no more
- require 1 to 8 A-Z characters anywhere in the string and no more
- require 1 to 8 0-9 characters anywhere in the string and no more
- require 1 to 8 symbols anywhere in the string and no more
- allow zero spaces

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/oS4mY2/2

**Sample text**

Note: the first example is from your commment, but it contains more than 8 lower case letters so it doesn't match.

```
aWoeed1#fde39393aii
aWoeed1#fde39393AII
```

**Sample Matches**

```
aWoeed1#fde39393AII
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 1 and
                             8 times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^a-z]*?                 any character except: 'a' to 'z' (0 or
                               more times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){1,8}                   end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 1 and
                             8 times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^0-9]*?                 any character except: '0' to '9' (0 or
                               more times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){1,8}                   end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 1 and
                             8 times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^A-Z]*?                 any character except: 'A' to 'Z' (0 or
                               more times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){1,8}                   end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 1 and
                             8 times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^!-\/:-@[-`{-           any character except: '!' to '\/', ':'
      ~]*?                     to '@', '[' to '`', '{' to '~' (0 or
                               more times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [!-\/:-@[-`{-~]          any character of: '!' to '\/', ':' to
                               '@', '[' to '`', '{' to '~'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){1,8}                   end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [!-\/:-@[-`{-~]          any character of: '!' to '\/', ':' to
                               '@', '[' to '`', '{' to '~'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9!-\/:-@[-      any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
  `{-~]{16,25}             '0' to '9', '!' to '\/', ':' to '@', '['
                           to '`', '{' to '~' (between 16 and 25
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: wow thats great thank U!!

I am making a helper for my Laravel framework that a user kan config what kind of password/validation must me used...

The length of the string, the min en max of the 0-9a-zA-Z & symbols etc

And this regex is just wonderful

Answer (score 0):

## Description

In your expression the look aheads like `(?=.*[A-Z]{1,})` are testing to see if you have 1 or more `A-Z`. These will return true if you have any number (greater than zero) of the desired character class. Having it continue testing to see if there are more than 1 match is just redundant.

`^(?=(?:[^a-z]*?[a-z]){1})(?=(?:[^0-9]*?[0-9]){1})(?=(?:[^A-Z]*?[A-Z]){1})(?=(?:[^!-\/:-@[-`{-~]*?[!-/:-@[-`{-~]){1})[a-zA-Z0-9!-\/:-@[-`{-~]{16,25}$`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- require the string to be 16-25 length
- require at least 1 `a-z` characters anywhere in the string
- require at least 1  `A-Z` characters anywhere in the string
- require at least 1  `0-9` characters anywhere in the string
- require at least 1 symbol anywhere in the string
- allow zero spaces

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/oS4mY2/3

**Sample text**

Note the last line doesn't match because it doesn't have a symbol

```
aWoeed1#fde39393aii
aWoeed1#fde39393AII
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1A
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
0.  [0-19]  `aWoeed1#fde39393aii`

MATCH 2
0.  [20-39] `aWoeed1#fde39393AII`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^a-z]*?                 any character except: 'a' to 'z' (0 or
                               more times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){1}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^0-9]*?                 any character except: '0' to '9' (0 or
                               more times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){1}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^A-Z]*?                 any character except: 'A' to 'Z' (0 or
                               more times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){1}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^!-\/:-@[-`{-           any character except: '!' to '\/', ':'
      ~]*?                     to '@', '[' to '`', '{' to '~' (0 or
                               more times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [!-\/:-@[-`{-~]          any character of: '!' to '\/', ':' to
                               '@', '[' to '`', '{' to '~'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){1}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9!-\/:-@[-      any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
  `{-~]{16,25}             '0' to '9', '!' to '\/', ':' to '@', '['
                           to '`', '{' to '~' (between 16 and 25
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```